# Using maven settings.xml for AWS account information

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, settings

I am trying to use maven for my AWS account information.
Here is my attempt:

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>kornhaus</id>
      <username>#####################</username>
      <password>###########################</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

However when I do this and try to run maven, I get the following error:

Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain

My username and password are correct. Perhaps I am misunderstanding which ID I am supposed to use?

Answer (score 0):

ID is the server ID, not the AWS account ID. Typically this ID can be found in the pom.xml as well.